# Copy shortcut not working in RStudio when using Cmd + c

Tags: rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

The Cmd+c keyboard shortcut to copy a text is not working in R studio (neither in the console as the editor). Copying by right clicking and through the menu works fine, and also in other programs Cmd+c works. Using Cmd+x and then Cmd+v does work in R studio however. I'm using the latest version of both R studio and R. I also tried an earlier version of R studio and R and the same problem occurs. What could be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Double check that Cmd C did not get bound to something odd by going to the Tools menu and opening Modify Keyboard Shortcuts... look to see if it was bound to some odd command.

Comment: In the Modify Keyboard Shortcuts I do not see it bound to another character... However, when I have created a plot in R and click the Cmd C it opens the plot (when I click it again it closes the plot and so on).

I also noted that the control + 2 does not move my cursus within R to the console, but I switch to my desktop 2 of the laptop. Could these two (and probably more functionalities that are not working properly) be caused by the same problem?

Comment: to clarify a bit further: I meant created a plot and clicked on zoom. Then cmd+C can be used to close and open the zoomed plot

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem!

First I went to Keyboard --> Shortcuts and unclicked all options (from launchpad & dock, mission control, keyboard etc etc). Afterwards I clicked "Restore Defaults".

Lastly, I went to Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> App Shortcuts --> + --> add a new shortcut, for all applications, called "Copy", shortcut: "Cmd C".
Now it works again!